# How to select only questions not yet answered by a user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a quiz and would like to show to the user only questions that were not answered by himself. How do I do that?

**models.py**

```
class Questao(models.Model):
    idQuestao = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        primary_key=True,
        null=False,
        verbose_name="ID da questão")

class Resposta(models.Model):
    idQuestao = models.ForeignKey(
        Questao,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="ID da questão")
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Usuário")
```

**views.py**

```
questao = Questao.objects.filter(tipoQuestao=1, resposta__usuario=request.user)\
    .exclude(idQuestao=Resposta.objects.filter())\
    .order_by("?")\
    .first()
```

EDIT

When I enter the quiz, I was asked the question E200501 to answer, but the one that was answered was the E200503.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code you showed: does it work? Which part does not work?

Comment: How is the resulting query different from what you want to obtain?

Comment: For your edited question: I want to know how you add the ID of your random question to your HTML form when rendering the template (are you using a hidden input field or URL parameter?); then I want to know how your view looks like that stores the new answer (how are you retrieving the question ID and is it finding the correct question?).

Comment: respostaform = RespostaForm(request.POST or None)
 if request.method == 'POST':
  if respostaform.is_valid():
   resp = respostaform.save(commit=False)
   resp.idQuestao = questao

Comment: When you enter if request.method == 'POST' :, the questao value is randomized again.

Comment: Why would you randomize the question again inside the POST of the form? You should send the corresponding question ID from the template with the POST request.

Comment: I would not like it to randomize again, this is the problem

Comment: One solution is to add a hidden input field to your template form with the name `idQuestao` and fill it with the correct data when rendering the template, so that the POST data contains the necessary data.

Comment: Cannot assign "'E200502'": "Resposta.idQuestao" must be a "Questao" instance.

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand. Can you edit the code and the error traceback into your question? Or even better: ask a new question with all the info, because this seems quite different from the original question.

Comment: Never mind, I found your new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331696/randomizing-again-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that whenever user answers to a question `Resposta` object is created if you simply want to return the `Questao` that user has not answered yet you just need `exclude()`

```
questao = Questao.objects.exclude(resposta__usuario=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

To exclude questions were the user has answered already I would suggest using [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions) (and maybe even [`Case/When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)) to count the related items in a single query and filter them out.

```
from django.db import models

questao = Questao.objects\
    .annotate(
        resp_count=models.Count(
            models.Case(
                models.When(resposta__usuario=request.user, then=1),
                output_field=models.IntegerField())))\
    .filter(tipoQuestao=1, resp_count=0)\
    .order_by("?")\
    .first()
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: So sometimes when I answer a question, it is loaded again and the form says another question has been answered. What may be happening?

Comment: @MurilodeJesus I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain or maybe show a screenshot?