# Randomizing again in Django

Tags: django, django-views

When I generate a quiz in django, the question value before if request.method == 'POST': is one and then changed. Follow the screenshots.

[image: Questão E200501]

[image: Questão E200503]
views.py

```
    questao = Questao.objects.annotate(resp_count=models.Count(models.Case(models.When(resposta__usuario=request.user, then=1),output_field=models.IntegerField()))).filter(resp_count=0,tipoQuestao=1).order_by("?").first()
    print (questao)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print (questao)
        respostaform = RespostaForm(request.POST or None)
        if respostaform.is_valid():
            resp = respostaform.save(commit=False)
            resp.idQuestao = questao
            resp.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Comment: On GET it takes "first" questao and renders it, on POST, it re-fetches questao so that's why it uses a different one. What you want to do is add questao as a hidden field on your form when you render it, and then, on POST, use that question ID to store it on your response.

Comment: Cannot assign "'E200502'": "Resposta.idQuestao" must be a "Questao" instance.

Comment: `resp.idQuestao_id = E200502`

Comment: For other readers: here is the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287955/how-to-select-only-questions-not-yet-answered-by-a-user-in-django) by the same user, where you can find related code (models, for example) to better understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should look something like this, where you only fetch a random question when the request IS NOT POST:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    respostaform = RespostaForm(request.POST or None)
    if respostaform.is_valid():
        resp = respostaform.save()
    return redirect(...)
else:
    questao = Questao.objects\
        .annotate(
            resp_count=models.Count(
                models.Case(
                    models.When(resposta__usuario=request.user, then=1),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField())))\
        .filter(resp_count=0,tipoQuestao=1)\
        .order_by("?")\
        .first()
    print(questao)
    return render(request, 'some template', {'questao': questao})
```

Your `RespostaForm` should include a field named `idQuestao` (You did not show the code of the form, but I assume it is a `ModelForm`).

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, friend. Works fine. My respostaform contais a hidden field named idQuestao.